# Django Add Record invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the model

TraceBack Error

```
Template error:
In template /Users/turntra/Files/laryks/staenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
   invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'07 08:49:15.819365'
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>
```

Upon opening the Model and trying to add a record I get the error **invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'07 08:49:15.819365'**

This **b'07 08:49:15.819365'** I have no idea where it comes from.

Please assist.

Comment: Please add your traceback error and also the lines that responsible for this error (If you know it) to your question.

Comment: @Roham I have added the traceback error.

Answer (score -1):

I made alot of changes to most of all of my models, moving from `DateTimeField`to `DateField` and `TimeField` precisely. This must have left my database in a inconsistence state. I ponder that is why, so the solution I found was to undo all migrations and place models back to the state where they were consistent then walk through proper transitioning from `DateTimeField`to `DateField`and `TimeField`by providing default values as I run the migrations again.